# what is blanket update in SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have a few update queries, and I need them as a blanket update.

```
update Table_A  set status=0 where task_type='AAA' and task_name='BBB';

update Table_A set status=0 where task_type='CCC' and task_name='DDD';

update Table_A  set status=0 where task_type='EEE' and task_name='FFF';
```

I need this to be a blanket update

Comment: `OR` maybe?  `(a and b) or (c and d) or (e and f)`

Comment: 1) Tag your question appropriately with the RDBMS platform you are _actually_ using. 2) What do you mean "blanket update"?  What's wrong with those updates?  What do you need them to do that they're not doing?  Do you mean you need just a single UPDATE statement to cover all 3 situations?

Comment: This will look very different whether you're using SQL Server or MySql. If it's really just three rows like this I can build something that will work the same, but if this is a sample of a larger set then you'll want to do it a little differently, where they have different syntaxes for this kind of UPDATE statement. In the meantime, I removed the tags to avoid reward bad tagging by gaining attention from people who primarily work with the wrong platform. Yes, this also means missing some people who use the right platform, but play silly games, win silly prizes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a single update that will cover all your scenarios - something like this

```
update Table_A  set status= 
    case 
        when task_type ='AAA' and task_name='BBB' then 0
        when  task_type='CCC' and task_name='DDD' then 0
        when task_type='EEE' and task_name='FFF' then 0
    end;
```

This works in MySQL, MSSQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL. I haven't tested it in Oracle

If you have other conditions then just extend the Case statement

Answer (score 0):

You can just combined all three where clauses with `or`

```
update Table_A  set status=0 
where (task_type='AAA' and task_name='BBB')
or (task_type='CCC' and task_name='DDD')
or (task_type='EEE' and task_name='FFF');
```